# Jenkins pipelines, shell, and pipes

Tags: shell, jenkins, pipe, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get a shell command with pipes working with Jenkins Pipelines. It's related to: [Jenkins pipeline sh does not seem to respect pipe in shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568201/jenkins-pipeline-sh-does-not-seem-to-respect-pipe-in-shell-command). I also found: [Jenkins pipeline, bash, and pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193645/jenkins-pipeline-bash-and-pipes?rq=1)

However, my success with it has been unsuccessful. I can literally copy/paste the resolution of the first post in my pipeline and it does work (at least it tries execute the shell, fails due to lack of pom.xml).

When I attempt to modify the shell command to my needs, it falls flat:

```
def bgd_discovery = $/eval "cf apps | grep ${appHost}.${host} | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sed 's/${args.appName}-bgd//'"/$
echo "${bgd_discovery}"
```

Jenkins throws a DSL method error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'eval "cf apps | grep [...app host...] | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sed 's' found among steps [...]
```

It seems to stop at first `/` of sed, but that's not the problem because this *does* work (from the first post):

```
def ver_script = $/eval "sed -n '/<version>/,/<version/p' pom.xml | head -1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*<\/*version>//g'"/$
```

Interestingly, here's another symptom to a problem: An added hyphen to the end of the `sed` regex

```
def bgd_discovery = $/eval "cf apps | grep ${appHost}.${host} | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sed 's/${args.appName}-bgd-//'"/$
```

Produced this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 26: expecting '}', found '' @ line 26, column 10.
   echo "${bgd_discovery}"
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to answer my own question now. It would appear there's something flakey with the quotes. I removed them for `sed` and things are functioning, even without the whole `eval` route. This works just fine:

```groovy
def current_deployment = sh (
        returnStdout: true,
        script: "cf apps | grep ${appName}.apps | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sed s/${appName}-bgd-//"
);
```